# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 not render font in Debain 10

Tags: intellij-idea, debian-buster

[image: font rendering problem in IntelliJ IDEA]

Same problem in method name while extracting method from code fragment.

Custom VM options have same problem
[image: Custom VM options font rendering problem]

Same in copy class
[image: copy class font rendering problem]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the font, selected in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | **Use custom font** and in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Font | **Font** is broken.

Try choosing different fonts there.

[image]
[image]

Comment: work after shutdown and start next day))) very strange.
I was restarted befor...